# Why my Nav Mesh properties changes automatically when i restart level?

Tags: unreal-engine4

am setting Nav mesh with the required properties and save the level but, when i restart level that time nav mesh reset or disable automatically.

Comment: Have a look for a tutorial on using the NavMeshBoundsVolume, you can verify that the mesh itself is generated by pressing `p` in the scene window.

Comment: thanks george, but thats not the issue